# show selected divs based on drop-down menu choice

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'd kindly ask for a help with following situation:

Let's say we have **divs** `DIV1`, `DIV2`, `DIV3` and `DIV4`.
Let's say we have **drop-down** menu with choices `CHOICE1`, `CHOICE2` and `CHOICE3`.

I'd like to achieve functionality described below:

- If user selects `CHOICE1`, show `DIV1`, hide others.
- If user selects `CHOICE2`, show `DIV1` and `DIV3`, hide others.
- If user selects `CHOICE3`, show `DIV2`, `DIV3` and `DIV4`, hide others.

You got the idea, I believe :-) Thanks for your help, Charlie.

Comment: I am a total noob with javascript and all the examples I've found so far were covering 1 choice -> 1 div scenario.

Comment: Are you using jquery or just javascript? Can you post the html and css part of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this. You have your menu items which when clicked get the index of the clicked item and then open the corresponding series of divs. The only trick with this approach is the div's and the list of menu items have to be in the same order.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu-container li').click(function(){
        var clickedIndex = $(this).index();
        $('.div-container div').css('display', 'none');
        $('.div-container div').eq(clickedIndex).css('display', 'block');
    });
});
```

Good Luck,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#choice").change(function(){
        $("div[id^='div']").hide();                
        var val = $(this).val();
        if(val == "CHOICE1"){
           $("#div1").show();
        }
        if(val == "CHOICE2"){
           $("#div1").show();
           $("#div3").show();
        }
    })
})​
```

Demo here : http://jsfiddle.net/6Vxw5/

Comment: Hi mgraph, thanks a lot for answering so fast! :-)

can you please let me know if I need to add something to drop-down menu code --> maybe call that function with onchange?

I'd appreciate a full example, including html code and css - it's worth a beer :-).

Comment: @Charlie if you want to use `onchange` see this : http://jsfiddle.net/6Vxw5/1/ it will only work in your html page

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:
0. Being your select something like...

```
<select name="mySelect">
    <option value="0">a</option>
    <option value="1">b</option>
</select>
```

1.- Set up an array which associates option values to divs:

```
var myDivs = [["div1"], ["div2", "div3"]]
```

2.- Set up a toggle visibility function onchange:

```
jQuery('select').change(toggleDivVisibility);
```

3.- Define the function:

```
function toggleDivVisibility() {
    jQuery('div').css('display', 'none');
    var divIds = myDivs[this.value];
    for(var d = 0, maxD = divIds.length; d++; d < maxD) {
        var divId = divIds[d];
        jQuery("#"+divId).css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

Some lines should be improved, obviously, but I think you'll get the idea.